# Retrieving Data in Webmatrix without 'foreach'

Tags: sql, loops, foreach, webmatrix

I want to retrieve a single item of data from my database to then use as a value for an input element. 
Using the below will retrieve each instance of `SubmittedBy` in the DB so results in multiple results.

```
var UserId = WebSecurity.CurrentUserId;

var db = Database.Open("testDB");
var selectQueryString = "Select SubmittedBy FROM Posts WHERE UserId=@0";

var data = db.Query(selectQueryString, UserId);

@foreach(var row in data)
{
    <input type="email" name="emailfrom" id="emailfrom" value="@SubmittedBy"/>  
}
```

How do I retrieve `SubmittedBy` so it only gives the one result i.e. without the foreach loop?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 3):

If by your data restriccions are you going to obtain 1 and only 1 value for an specific UserId, you could use

```
   var SubmyttedValue = db.QueryValue(selectQueryString, UserId);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a method created specifically for this purpose called QuerySingle - just change your query like this:

```
var data = db.QuerySingle(selectQueryString, UserId);
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Actually I don't think this will produce the desired result for the OP or at least "data" won't be the type they think it is. Perhaps something like `var data = db.QuerySingle(selectQueryString, UserId).columnName` would be better. Or, of course, you could just use Ps1CsCpp's answer, as it achieves the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Change your query like this:

```
Select SubmittedBy FROM Posts WHERE UserId=@0 LIMIT 1
```